# How to modify failure report for specific tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have custom fixture, which collects information about queries to DB during test, and in case of failure of test uses  that fixture, I want to add information collected by fixture to report. How can I do that?

UPDATE

How it looks like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import db
import pytest

def make_cursor_handler():
    ...
    return cursor_handler, list_with_log

@contextmanager
def wrap_cursor():
    old_handler = db.cursor_handler
    db.cursor_handler, list_with_log = make_cursor_handler()
    yield list_with_log
    db.cursor_handler = old_handler

@pytest.yield_fixture
def cursor_fixture():
    with wrap_cursor() as log:
        yield log #How would I print it inside error report without including it in assert message?
```

Comment: please give some more detail if you can.

Answer (score 5):

You can use pytest-capturelog that captures all log messages written within a test, including during setup and teardown. So whatever you log is part of your report, which can be really useful (and we indeed use it in company I'm employed; although we use nose, which handles it without any plugins AFAIK).

```
pip install pytest-capturelog
```

Then you can log messages anywhere during the test (setup, teardown, fixtures, in helper functions), pytest-capturelog should handle it:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def setup_function(function):
    log.info("setup log message")

def test_it():
    log.info("test log message")
    assert False
```

The result (see `Captured log`):

```
==================== test session starts =====================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.4 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
plugins: capturelog
collected 1 items 

file.py F

========================== FAILURES ==========================
__________________________ test_it ___________________________

    def test_it():
        log.info("test log message")
>       assert False
E       assert False

file.py:10: AssertionError
------------------------ Captured log ------------------------
file.py                      6 INFO     setup log message
file.py                      9 INFO     test log message
================== 1 failed in 0.01 seconds ==================
```

Comment: The output is exactly what I need. I will accept this if there wili not be solutions without external plugins.

Comment: While this sure would work is there any reason why you can't just use `print "msg"` in the fixture instead of using logging?  This will appear in the captured stdout section when the test fails (and requires no extra plugins).

Comment: print won't give you context of logging like file, line and log level. That's usually ok for small projects, but not for more complicated project. And well behaved third-party libraries (requests, django, ...) are using logging anyway, so you would loose all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Can you call the report header with the additional information or have your custom fixture print additional information?  It would look something like the examples they gave on pytest.org.

**Report Header Code [here](https://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#adding-info-to-test-report-header)**

```
def pytest_report_header(config):
    return "Additional Information here"
```

**Fixture Code [here](https://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures)**

If you post your code I think we can better troubleshoot.

```
@pytest.fixture
def something(request):
    def fin():
        # request.node is an "item" because we use the default
        # "function" scope
        if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
            print "setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid
        elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
            if request.node.rep_call.failed:
                print "executing test failed", request.node.nodeid
    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Print works, but it's not very flexible. It's great if you really want to isolate the output of your test and don't want to see anything else. If you're interested in seeing errors from various packages and components of your application (django, httplib, etc), then you want to use logging.

To get logging output in the test report without plugins, just setup the logging to output to stdout/stderr; this basically turns the log calls into super-powered print calls. Then, if you run pytest **without the -s switch**, the output will be added to the test results.

Here's how to configure logging; make sure to execute it early on!

```
import logging
from sys import stdout, stderr

# this is our root logger, give it the name you want
log = logging.getLogger("myScript")  

# prevents adding the same handlers over and over again if your script is read multiple times
if not len(log.handlers):
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # we are setting a file log, and also redirecting to stdout/stderr
    logger_file_handler = logging.FileHandler('myScript.debug.log')
    console_flow_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
    console_error_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stderr)
    # set their levels. file gets all, console gets info and up, stderr gets warnings and up
    logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_flow_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_error_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    # ok, add them!
    log.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    log.addHandler(console_flow_handler)
    log.addHandler(console_error_handler)
    # don't propagate messages to parent (root), else we get duplicates - this may or may not fit your situation
    log.propagate = False
```

Then in your test, you can just do this:

```
import logging; log = logging.getLogger("myScript.TestName")

def test_something():
    log.debug("This only goes into the log file")
    log.info("This will be printed to console too")
    log.warning("This goes to stdout and stderr - pytest will print stderr into its own section so that you can see them quickly")
    assert 0  # if it fails, you get the logs. if it pass, you get nothing.
```